# Plot all column values in a single graph Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have a set of wine data. The column names are wine descriptors. Each row represents a different bottle of wine. If the wine has a descriptor in its description (from another dataset), the cell in that column is filled with the price. Otherwise, it is NaN.

I want to create a graph that compares the descriptors to the price. The x-axis should be each descriptor. The points above represent the price of a bottle. The information here shows a graph like what I'm looking for, but doesn't quite work for my data. https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html

The code below gave me very close to what I am looking for:

```
count = 1
for col in wine_desc.columns:
    plt.scatter([count for i in range(len(wine_desc["aftertaste"]))], wine_desc[col])
    count +=1
```

However, I want the x tickmarks to be the wine descriptor labels. I would also like to be able to do things like add a title, axis labels, etc. and this method does not allow for that.

Is there a way to do this with my data in its current form, or perhaps a way I could transform the data to make this work?

Edit: Here is a subset of my data:

```
wine_desc = pd.DataFrame({"aftertaste":[0, 12, 0], "alcoholic": [0, 0, 14], "aroma": [20, 12, 0]})
wine_desc.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Which looks like:

```
   aftertaste  alcoholic  aroma
0         NaN        NaN   20.0
1        12.0        NaN   12.0
2         NaN       14.0    NaN
```

I want aftertaste, alcoholic, and aroma to be my x labels. Above aftertaste a point at 12, above alcoholic a point above 14, above aroma a point at 20 and a point at 12. I would like them to be side by side all on one graph so I can quickly see if one wine note raises the price.

Comment: We'll need a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help with this.

Comment: Can you show us your example data and how it's formatted? It sounds like a bar graph would be appropriate and you can create those using [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/). There's also an option to use pandas df as the input data.

Comment: I do have this in a pandas dataframe. I don't think a bar graph will work here because I'm not trying to count the number of wines that have "aroma" in the notes, I'm trying to visualize what notes affect the price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `seaborn.stripplot` do what you want. 
I had to modify you're original dataframe.

## Code :

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns

wine_desc = pd.DataFrame({"aftertaste":[0, 12, 0, 15, 12, 13, 10, 14, 12, 4],
                          "alcoholic": [14, 12, 12, 12, 13,14, 15, 12, 0, 0], 
                          "aroma": [22, 15, 18, 17, 19, 11, 1, 20, 13, 0]})
wine_desc.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
df = pd.DataFrame([(colname, wine_desc[colname][i]) for i in range(len(wine_desc)) for colname in wine_desc.columns], 
                 columns=['col', 'values'])

sns.stripplot(x = 'col', y='values', data=df)
```

## plot

[image: ![display]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlEVl.png)

Comment: Thanks! I think this definitely would have worked but took too long to load on my full dataset. I used this idea though to create tuples `(colname, median)` and plotted it like this, and I think that will be good enough.

Comment: Hi, there is other functions you should check  : [seaborn.boxplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) / [seaborn.boxenplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxenplot.html)